# Aggregating Data Frame in Deedle

Tags: deedle

I'm a newbie to Deedle.

Given this data frame

```
     date       account custodian ticker qty     pnl price

0 -> 1/1/2013   ACCT #1 CUST#1    AAPL   1000   5000    95
1 -> 1/1/2013   ACCT #1 CUST#2    AAPL    200    400    94
2 -> 1/2/2013   ACCT #1 CUST#1    AAPL    100    300    93
```

I would like to aggregate columns - sum qty / pnl columns and average price. I want an output similar to the following below

```
     date       account ticker qty     pnl price

0 -> 1/1/2013   ACCT #1 AAPL   1200   5400    94.5
1 -> 1/2/2013   ACCT #1 AAPL    100    300    93
```

My Approach so far:

```
let sumCols = df |> Frame.aggregateRowsBy ["date"; "account"; "ticker"] ["pnl"; "qty"] Stats.sum
let avgCols = df |> Frame.aggregateRowsBy ["date"; "account"; "ticker"] ["price"] Stats.mean
```

I'm having trouble joining / merging these two data frames. I get the following error.

System.InvalidOperationException: Combining vectors failed - both vectors have a value.
   at Deedle.VectorHelpers.get_AtMostOne@161-1.Invoke(Tuple`2 tupledArg) in c:\Tomas\Public\Deedle\src\Deedle\Vectors\VectorHelpers.fs:line 162
   at Deedle.Vectors.ArrayVector.ArrayVectorBuilder.Deedle-Vectors-IVectorBuilder-Build[T](VectorConstruction command, IVector`1[] arguments) in c:\Tomas\Public\Deedle\src\Deedle\Vectors\ArrayVector.fs:line 198

> at Deedle.Frame`2.Join(Frame`2 otherFrame, JoinKind kind, Lookup lookup) in c:\Tomas\Public\Deedle\src\Deedle\Frame.fs:line 272
>      at .$FSI_0059.main@()

Comment: Having the exact same problem although in C#.. did you have any luck in solving the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Deedle frames cannot be joined if they have columns with same name.

If you want to join the last 2 frames you have to extract the not common columns from one and add it to the other one.

For example you can do the following:

```
sumCols?price <- avgCols?price
```

and you have the column price in the `sumCols` frame.

If you need a more sofisticated join, you can think to create first a new frame from the columns you want to take, and then join it with the other frame, as the following example:

```
let df2 = Frame.ofColumns ["price" => avgCols?price]
let df3 = Frame.join JoinKind.Outer sumCols df2
```

I hope it can be useful.